# ocmod, replace in controller Opencart 2.0.1.1

Tags: opencart2.x

I did asked this question on OpenCart's forum but didn't get any answers so i try to ask it here instead and hopefully get a good answer :).

Ok let's go to my problem. I am trying to remove the required field for product name on product page in admin. This is because if you have a multilingual installation but only want to name the product for 1 language you get error if you don't name it on every language (Yeah this is stupid).

Well. I do know how to make this possible and wanted to make it with the new OCMOD. I have tested it in core files "live" and it work just as it supposed to. But when i implement it in an ocmod xml file it doesn't want to work.

```
       <file path="admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl">
      <operation>
         <search><![CDATA[
                  <div class="form-group required">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-name<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>"><?php echo $entry_name; ?></label>]]></search>
         <add position="replace"><![CDATA[
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-name<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>"><?php echo $entry_name; ?></label>
]]></add>
      </operation>
   </file>

   <file path="admin/controller/catalog/product.php">
      <operation>
         <search><![CDATA[
      foreach ($this->request->post['product_description'] as $language_id => $value) {
         if ((utf8_strlen($value['name']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($value['name']) > 255)) {
            $this->error['name'][$language_id] = $this->language->get('error_name');
         }

         if ((utf8_strlen($value['meta_title']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($value['meta_title']) > 255)) {
            $this->error['meta_title'][$language_id] = $this->language->get('error_meta_title');
         }
      }
]]></search>
         <add position="replace"><![CDATA[

]]></add>
      </operation>
  </file>


   <file path="admin/controller/setting/setting.php">
      <operation>
         <search><![CDATA[
      if (isset($this->error['name'])) {
         $data['error_name'] = $this->error['name'];
      } else {
         $data['error_name'] = '';
      }
]]></search>
         <add position="replace"><![CDATA[

]]></add>
      </operation>
   </file>
```

I hope someone here can help me with my little problem. All should work fine, but somehow this won't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem, what I do (as a ugly workaround) while I get an answer or find the correct way is a single line search with index, like:

```
<search index="131"><![CDATA[
    }
]]></search>
```

So instead of search:

```
<search><![CDATA[
    <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-name<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>"><?php echo $entry_name; ?></label>
]]></search>
```

You can use something like:

```
<search index="X"><![CDATA[
    <div class="form-group required">
]]></search>
```

Remember that index is 0 based, and also the line number in the logs.